# Range copy not copying?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a range of cells used as a template to a new sheet after entering the number of sheets desired. I am able to create/delete the sheets as needed but for some reason the range copy is not actually copying (but the source and range itself seem to be valid.  [Sample is located here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7cbc519fdc5ef1c1f308f61a2731d88f20190208205047/d24664), Thanks! Below is the relevant code as well

```
xOffset = Sheets("Initial Estimate").index 'initial sheet
Set xActiveSheet = Sheets(xOffset)   'sheet is not first tab

xNumber = Worksheets("Initial Estimate").Range("$B$1").Value 'input value
 For I = 1 To xNumber Step 1

        CheckSheetName = "" 'clear checkname or else get false positives

       xName = "Estimated Invoice 0" + CStr(I)

    CheckSheetName = Worksheets(xName).Name

    If CheckSheetName = "" Then 'doesnt exist

        Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = xName
        CheckSheetName = Worksheets(xName).Name

        MsgBox "inside " + CheckSheetName 'exists here, so should be able to copy right?

      xActiveSheet.Range("A17:H34").Copy Destination:=Worksheets(xName).Range = ("A1")   ' copy initial sheet range to xName sheet

    End If

Next I
```

Comment: Change `Range = ("A1") ` to `Range("A1") `

Comment: Oops! Thanks, that did it.

Comment: Feel free to make a post if you want that sweet sweet answer point

Comment: Nick, that is more a typo than an issue.  You are obviously aware of how to refer to a range.  Typo correction, where they help you, are not usually helpful to future readers, and as such are usually closed.